# How do I specify my image's position?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have a problem with my web site position, this is my CSS:

My web site: http://jsfiddle.net/maxspeed200/qYCUJ/5/embedded/result/

My CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/maxspeed200/qYCUJ/6/

The problem is: I have this two images one in header and the second in content & jquery slide show all this elements work good and I modified their position on my computer BUT when I take my website index to another computer all images move left or right (Pushed from its place)

And I work in my Dreamweaver in split view I create my design n n set my images in their places when I go to view my web site in browser (Mozilla/IE) I see my images not in same places I know it is a problem in CSS but how do I modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there in an `absolute` position element so give his parent position `relative` now give `position: relative;` to  `.container` DIV. like this:

```
.container {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    height: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
   }
```